# Login authentication error in python pyqt5 and how to set instance variable in lable?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I am having trouble running if part of code where user name and password is wrong.program does not show any error.
And how can i set  userfullname of Index class to lable in admin_object = userFullname.setText() ?

```
import sqlite3

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

from Login_form import Login_form
from Admin_Home_form import AdminHome_Form


class Index(QtWidgets.QDialog, Login_form):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.loginFormDesign(self)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_check)

    def login_check(self):
        uname = self.U_name_text.text()
        password = self.pass_text.text()
        # self.userfullname = userfullname
        connection = sqlite3.connect("taylorDB.db")
        result = connection.execute("SELECT USER_EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE USER_EMAIL = ? AND USER_PASSWORD = ?",
                                (uname, password))
        for dbemail in result:  # After this code does not work if value does not match
            print(dbemail[0])
            if dbemail[0] != uname:
                buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Login Invalid', "Check User Name or Password!",
                                               QMessageBox.Close)
                if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Close:
                    print("invalid login")
            else:
                result = connection.execute("SELECT USER_FULLNAME FROM USERS WHERE USER_EMAIL = ?", (dbemail))
                self.userfullname = result.fetchone()
                print(self.userfullname)
                self.accept()


class admin_operation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, AdminHome_Form, Index):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.adminHomeFormDesign(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login_object = Index()
    admin_object = admin_operation()

    if login_object.exec() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        # admin_object.userFullname.setText()   #I want to set the value of userfullname here?
        admin_object.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My basic are not so strong please guide me .

Comment: share your .db file

Comment: upload it to dropbox, drive, github, etc and share the link to download it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ndmSnquqVDUu9h0AXXQuk0udYJ-aVVLw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: share `Login_form.py` and `Admin_Home_form.py`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wCvewBaHVVOqXC5PrrH8xqvHHKMSc1kK?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must improve your logic, instead of the select return `USER_EMAIL` must return the `USER_FULLNAME` so you avoid making a new query, on the other hand to get the results you must use `fetchall()`, this will return a tuple of the results, if no results will be empty, otherwise there will be results. In your case, I assume that you restrict the `USER_EMAIL` to being unique so that the result will be a tuple of a single element. That data you keep in one member of the class, and you set it in the other window.

On the other hand it is not necessary that admin_operation inherit from Index, so delete it.

---

```
import sqlite3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QDialog, QMainWindow, QApplication

from Login_form import Login_form
from Admin_Home_form import AdminHome_Form


class Index(QDialog, Login_form):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.loginFormDesign(self)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_check)

    def login_check(self):
        uname = self.U_name_text.text()
        password = self.pass_text.text()
        connection = sqlite3.connect("taylorDB.db")
        result = connection.execute("SELECT USER_FULLNAME FROM USERS WHERE USER_EMAIL = ? AND USER_PASSWORD = ?",
                                    (uname, password)).fetchall()

        if result:
            self.userfullname = result[0][0]
            self.accept()
        else:
            buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Login Invalid', "Check User Name or Password!",
                                                   QMessageBox.Close)
            if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Close:
                print("invalid login")
                # self.reject()


class Admin_operation(QMainWindow, AdminHome_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.adminHomeFormDesign(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login_object = Index()
    admin_object = Admin_operation()

    if login_object.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
        admin_object.userFullname.setText(login_object.userfullname)
        admin_object.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ok that is working fin.but i didn't understand this code self.userfullname = result[0][0] also what is use of if login_object.exec() == QDialog.Accepted: ?

Comment: @user3135049 So that you understand, for example let's say you look for the emails and the names of all, then it will be a list of tuples where each tuple will be an email and a name. that is, `result[i][0]` refers to the mail of the i-th result and `result[i][1]` will be the name of the i-th result. in your case it only has one result (assuming the uniqueness of the email) and that it has only one field so to access it you must use [0][0]

Comment: ok thanks and what about if login_object.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:

Comment: QDialog offers 2 methods, accept() and reject(), these methods are used to close the window, but in the case of accept the window return the Accepted state through exec_(), and in the case of reject() returns Rejected, in If you log in correctly, accept() is used, so the status is Accepted.

Comment: if i have two .py files like main.py file above .how do i interconnect them so a sequence of events are executed?